# Sharing a single property across multiple cshtml pages in Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor

I'm struggling to share a properties value across components in Blazor. Basically I have a button with an onclick event this sets a value on a function depending on the value another cshtml page should react to the value and it doesn't. The issue is that because both cshtml pages inherit the same function they have their own instance of the function. Here's my code so far:

the Function:

```
public class MenuFunctions : BlazorComponent, IMenuFunctions
{

    public bool CollapseNavMenu
    {
        get ; set;

    }

    public void ToggleNavMenu()
    {
        CollapseNavMenu = !CollapseNavMenu;
    }
}
```

The main button on NavMenuToggleComponent.cshtml:

```
@inherits MenuFunctions 

<div class="pl-4  navbar navbar-dark">
   <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-brand main-button" title="MENU" onclick=@ToggleNavMenu>
    MENU
   </button>
</div>
```

my NavMenu.cshtml file:

```
@inherits MenuFunctions


<div class="@(CollapseNavMenu ? "collapse" : null)" onclick=@ToggleNavMenu>
<ul class="nav flex-column">
    <li class="nav-item px-3">
        <NavLink class="nav-link" href="home">
            <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home
        </NavLink>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item px-3">
        <NavLink class="nav-link" href="frontpage">
            <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Front Page
        </NavLink>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item px-3">
        <NavLink class="nav-link" href="counter">
            <span class="oi oi-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Counter
        </NavLink>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item px-3">
        <NavLink class="nav-link" href="" Match=NavLinkMatch.All>
            <span class="oi oi-account-login" aria-hidden="true"></span> Login
        </NavLink>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

putting it all together in my MainLayout.cshtml

```
@inherits BlazorLayoutComponent

<NavMenuToggleComponent></NavMenuToggleComponent>
<div class="sidebar">
   <NavMenu />
</div>

<div class="main">

<div class="top-row px-4">
    <a href="http://blazor.net" target="_blank" class="ml-md-auto">About</a>
    <NavLink class="nav-link pull-right" href="logout">
        <span class="oi oi-account-logout" aria-hidden="true"></span> Logout
    </NavLink>
</div>

<div class="content px-4">
    @Body
</div>
</div>
```

so when I click the button in NavMenuToggleComponent.cshtml I want the CollapseNavMenu to react in the NavMenu.cshtml file

If I remove the use of the interface, then inject the components onto the pages as opposed to Inherit and then add the following into the startup:

```
services.AddSingleton<MenuFunctions>();
```

the pages will load, but I still get the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The solution here would be to bring the shared property to the place where it is common, in this case the `MainLayout.cshtml` and not make the components dependent on a common interface.

So the `MainLayout.cshtml` would hold the state in a new property and that property is bound to the two components.

You should not use DI for component classes, only for service providing classes and alike.

Comment: Because I  have placed the code in a component (e.g. MenuFunctions) as opposed to using `@functions` in the bottom of the page, my MainLayout.cshtml already inherits from BlazorLayoutComponent. By placing the code in the NavMenuToggleComponent.cshtml directly in MainLayout (I had this originally), I cannot add a second `@inherits...` into the MainLayout.cshtml, which is what forced me to split the code out from this page in the first place